# Don't allow elements to overflow on y-axis

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have a div with a fixed height. When I resize my browser window and the div's width becomes smaller, the elements inside the div jump below expanding the height. How can I make the elements visible by adding a horizontal scrollbar?

I have tried all CSS scroll properties, but could't make it work:

```
.dhButtonToolbar{
    position:absolute;
    top:6px;
    left:0;
    bottom: 5px;
    width: 60px;

    background-color:yellow;
    border:0px solid white;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top: 5px;

}

@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) { 
    .dhButtonToolbar {
        height: 55px;
        left:5px;
       overflow-y:auto; //here my elements jump below I want to add a horizontall scrollbar
        right: 5px; 
    }
```

JSFidlee: http://jsfiddle.net/x7xm3/2/

Try resizing and elements will fall below!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a body and give it a `min-width`. Is **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/x7xm3/11/)** what you wanted?.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No that is not the problem. I your fiddle elemts are verticall I want them to be horizontall all the time and when there is no space just a scrollbar.

Comment: You wanted the horizontal scroll bar if the screen wasnt big enough. Else,do give a better description

Comment: That is true but also I want elements to be horizontally positioned.

Comment: Please check the link in the answer again. Hope this edit solves your issue. http://jsfiddle.net/x7xm3/11/

Comment: That's it. Just another thing is missing. How to put the scrollbar inside the div.

Comment: add - `overflow-x` in `parent` class.

Comment: put it in an appropriate class and it will fix it. Think it over.

Answer (score 0):

I change in your jsfiddle. please check this.

```
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x7xm3/16/
```

It completely working.please check.

Comment: @Jacob i change in your jsfiddle. please check 'http://jsfiddle.net/x7xm3/16/' this fiddle. it is now working.